# Convert anchor point tool one side curved one side straight

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool

When working on a shape using the pen tool, I want to curve one side but keep the other side straight. However when I convert it curves both sides. I have previously remedied this by cutting the paths and then rejoining. This is probably a basic question but I never seem to figure it out when I am using the pen tool and it is quite annoying.

[image]
[image]

I am drawing a bustier for a fashion drawing so I wanted to keep the side of the bodice unchanged while adjusting the neckline of the bodice but the curve changes both sides

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to do, a screenshot perhaps showing what you have tried or what has failed, or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you converting the anchor to a curve point if you don't want it to be a curve?

Comment: I suggest you try using the Pen Tool, without resorting to converting anchor points. There should be no need to do that if you understand how the tool works.  Find a drawing of the item of clothing, paste it on a layer dimmed to 50%, and practice using the Pen Tool on top of it.  See [this example](https://imgur.com/a/5EUt5Kp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Convert Point Tool** works on Bezier *handles* as well. It will "break" the symmetry of the existing smooth point and convert it to a corner point (making each side of the point independent).

Simply click-drag a Bezier handle with the **Convert Point Tool** (Located under the Pen tool in the toolbar)

You could also select the point and then click the "corner point" button on the control bar across the top of the screen.

Comment: Ahaa great thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you click anchor point with Anchor point tool (Shift + C) it will become straight.
If you click and drag — it will become curved.
If you double click one of handles — it will become strait from one side
If you click and drag one of handles — it will become independent from both sides